# List of installed gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a Ruby method I can call to get the list of installed gems?

I  want to parse the output of `gem list`.

***Is there a different way to do this?***

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Gem command is included with Ruby 1.9+ now, and is a standard addition to Ruby pre-1.9.

```
require 'rubygems'

name = /^/i
dep = Gem::Dependency.new(name, Gem::Requirement.default)
specs = Gem.source_index.search(dep)
puts specs[0..5].map{ |s| "#{s.name} #{s.version}" }
# >> Platform 0.4.0
# >> abstract 1.0.0
# >> actionmailer 3.0.5
# >> actionpack 3.0.5
# >> activemodel 3.0.5
# >> activerecord 3.0.5
```

---

Here's an updated way to get a list:

```
require 'rubygems'

def local_gems
   Gem::Specification.sort_by{ |g| [g.name.downcase, g.version] }.group_by{ |g| g.name }
end
```

Because `local_gems` relies on `group_by`, it returns a hash of the gems, where the key is the gem's name, and the value is an array of the gem specifications. The value is an array of the instances of that gem that is installed, sorted by the version number.

That makes it possible to do things like:

```
my_local_gems = local_gems()

my_local_gems['actionmailer']
# => [Gem::Specification.new do |s|
#       s.authors = ["David Heinemeier Hansson"]
#       s.date = Time.utc(2013, 12, 3)
#       s.dependencies = [Gem::Dependency.new("actionpack",
#         Gem::Requirement.new(["= 4.0.2"]),
#         :runtime),
#        Gem::Dependency.new("mail",
#         Gem::Requirement.new(["~> 2.5.4"]),
#         :runtime)]
#       s.description = "Email on Rails. Compose, deliver, receive, and test emails using the familiar controller/view pattern. First-class support for multipart email and attachments."
#       s.email = "david@loudthinking.com"
#       s.homepage = "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
#       s.licenses = ["MIT"]
#       s.name = "actionmailer"
#       s.require_paths = ["lib"]
#       s.required_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new([">= 1.9.3"])
#       s.requirements = ["none"]
#       s.rubygems_version = "2.0.14"
#       s.specification_version = 4
#       s.summary = "Email composition, delivery, and receiving framework (part of Rails)."
#       s.version = Gem::Version.new("4.0.2")
#       end]
```

And:

```
puts my_local_gems.map{ |name, specs| 
  [ 
    name,
    specs.map{ |spec| spec.version.to_s }.join(',')
  ].join(' ') 
}
# >> actionmailer 4.0.2
...
# >> arel 4.0.1,5.0.0
...
# >> ZenTest 4.9.5
# >> zucker 13.1
```

The last example is similar to the `gem query --local` command-line, only you have access to all the information for a particular gem's specification.

Comment: Should be noted, "Dependency.new w/ a regexp is deprecated" now.

Answer (score 427):

This lists all the gems I have installed.

```
gem query --local
```

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-list

Listing all installed gems

Comment: there is a better answer in the question itself `gem list`.

Comment: `gem list` did exactly what I needed, and it's a lot simpler and easier to recall when on the CLI. Why so many commands to do one thing?

Comment: Difference between a)gem list, b)gem query and c)gem query --local please. All three seem having same line numbers.

Answer (score 36):

Both

```
gem query --local
```

and

```
 ruby -S gem list --local
```

list 69 entries

While

```
ruby -e 'puts Gem::Specification.all_names'
```

return 82

I used `wc -l` to get the numbers. Not sure if that is the right way to check. Tried to redirect the output to text files and diffed but that didn't help - will need to compare manually one by one.

Comment: The reason is simple. The first command only adds 1 entry per gem and lists the versions in brackets on the same line. The last `ruby` command lists each gem version on a separate line. For e.g.:  `sass (3.3.14, 3.3.7, 3.3.6, 3.2.19)` vs.

    `sass-3.3.14`,
    `sass-3.3.7`,
    `sass-3.3.6`,
    `sass-3.2.19`

Answer (score 11):

There's been a method for this for ages:

```rb
ruby -e 'puts Gem::Specification.all_names'
```

Comment: ruby -e 'puts Gem::Specification.all_names' gives me "-e:1: uninitialized constant Gem (NameError)" How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

```
Gem::Specification.map {|a| a.name}
```

However, if your app uses Bundler it will return only list of **dependent** local gems. To get all installed:

```
def all_installed_gems
   Gem::Specification.all = nil    
   all = Gem::Specification.map{|a| a.name}  
   Gem::Specification.reset
   all
end
```

Comment: This gives `NoMethodError: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass` when I use it (in a `rails console`).

Answer (score 6):

use this code (in console mode):

```
Gem::Specification.all_names
```

Comment: can you improve your answer?

Comment: improved or let me know what exactly you don't like in my answer

Comment: This could use an explanation of what this adds to existing answers. Why should I use this code? What does it do? How is it different than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353187/6243352) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017885/6243352)?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a really nice one-liner to print all the Gems along with their version, homepage, and description:

```
Gem::Specification.sort{|a,b| a.name <=> b.name}.map {|a| puts "#{a.name} (#{a.version})"; puts "-" * 50; puts a.homepage; puts a.description; puts "\n\n"};nil
```

Answer (score 3):

A more modern version would be to use something akin to the following...

```
require 'rubygems'
puts Gem::Specification.all().map{|g| [g.name, g.version.to_s].join('-') }
```

NOTE: very similar the first part of an answer by Evgeny... but due to page formatting, it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 3):

Try it in the terminal:

```
ruby -S gem list --local
```

Comment: Notice that the OP wanted a Ruby *method*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get the files (gems) from the gems directory?

```
gemsdir = "gems directory"
gems = Dir.new(gemsdir).entries
```

Answer (score 1):

From within your debugger type `$LOAD_PATH` to get a list of your gems. If you don't have a debugger, install pry:

```
gem install pry
pry
Pry(main)> $LOAD_PATH
```

This will output an array of your installed gems.