# How to check gem version within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was thinking about integrating a little feature into my CMS that checks for new releases of the gems that are installed. Is there a way to check the current installed version of a Gem from within the application/rails console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can access the rubygems api via the `Gem` class:

```
Gem.latest_version_for "pry"

# => Gem::Version.new("0.9.12.6")
```

To get the list of current gems, you can try this.

```
gems = Gem::Specification.sort_by{ |g| [g.name.downcase, g.version] }.group_by{ |g| g.name }
gems["pry"].version
# => Gem::Version.new("0.9.12.4")
```

Blatantly stolen from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177634/list-of-installed-gems)