# Conditional ruby gem dependencies within a gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm building a rails engine which uses foreign keys in migrations.

```
    add_foreign_key "theblog_content_nodes",
                    "theblog_content_statuses", column: :content_status_id
```

From the version `4.2` rails supports foreign keys by itself but before we used `foreigner` gem for this. If we try to use `foreigner` with `rails 4.2` and newer we get an error.

So since I'm going to support rails starting from 4.0.1 I have to use conditional dependency in my gemspec.

I found possible solution [here](https://www.tiredpixel.com/2014/01/05/curses-conditional-ruby-gem-installation-within-a-gemspec/) but I have no idea how to check rails version in the gemspec.

```
# sidekiq-spy.gemspec

if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.1'
  spec.add_development_dependency "curses", "~> 1.0"
end
```

**NOTE:**

I have another temporary solution: I just check `Foreigner` availability in my migrations. If it is unavailable I just don't create foreign keys:

```
if defined?(Foreigner)
  add_foreign_key "theblog_content_nodes",
                  "theblog_content_statuses", column: :content_status_id
end
```

But I'd like to add `foreigner` dependency for old rails versions.

Comment: Did you think of providing two different versions of your gem for that scenarios?

Comment: @iltempo, I can even use the one version for both scenarios. Just add note that we have to add `gem "foreigner"` to `Gemfile` if Rails version is less than `4.2` and we want to use foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access rails version, we can use something like below (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5177807/794242)):

```
require 'rubygems'

rails_gem = Gem::Specification.select {|z| z.name == "rails"}.max_by {|a| a.version}
p rails_gem.version.version
#=> "4.2.5"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems we have no access to `Rails` inside the gemspec.

I've just got the following error:

`uninitialized constant Rails from
  /Users/kont/projects/theblog/theblog.gemspec:21:in 'block in <main>'`

Comment: Updated the answer to use `rubygems` API.  Please check whether this will work for you

Comment: I tried this in both engine itself and in the app using this engine. It seems to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: Recently The CI failed with the following error:
`There was a NoMethodError while loading theblog.gemspec:
undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass from
  /Users/kont/projects/drevo/theblog/theblog.gemspec:26:in `block in <main>'`

I found that `Gem::Specification` does not contain `Rails` yet