# Building a Ruby gem to collect all local gems in a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I want to build a Ruby gem to collect all local gems in a project, I don't know the best practice for that.

should i parse the Gemfile somehow and get the gems list from it? or there are libraries to make that?

also, How can i make my gem global, just like Linux commands, what i mean is if my gem name is `gemlocator` and i put it on specific place in my Linux environment, it will enable me to open the terminal and `cd` to my Ruby project then write `gemlocator` to list the gems used in the project.

Comment: Does this question relate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177634/list-of-installed-gems If I understood what you mean by `collect`, so it may be helpful. Also you can use `bundle show` or `bundle list`. did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your Gemfile using `Gem::Specification`. The class contains all information of the gem.

```
Gem::Specification.map {|gem| gem.name}
```

Comment: this gives all gems in the system, i want to parse specifc GemFile