# List Gems from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

From rails console, how can I list the loaded gems in my environment?

I am using Gemfile and Rails 5. I've searched around with no results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post has a detailed explanation of what you seem to be asking for: 
[List of installed gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177634/list-of-installed-gems)

```
Gem::Specification.all_names
```

Comment: Please post an answer here instead of a link before I can accept this. I like `Gem::Specification.all_names`

Comment: All set : ) Glad to have helped